# Adb Tool showing No Devices Found

Tags: adb, custom-roms

I had flashed v10 stock rom in my coolped note 3 plus,
I was done successfully,
But after that My device stuck in FastMMI mode,
Everyone suggesting me that enable usb ddebugging, but how can i enable it even my devices isn'n starting?
May anybody tell me that how to exit from 
Fastmmi mode?

Comment: What does adb devices output ?

Comment: What is ADB devices output? may you please explain,

Comment: What you see on the screen when you type adb devices

Comment: USB debugging available on Settings->Developer Options. To activate developer option, you need to tap multiple times on build number.(For some devices it will be by tapping Custom Os version(Eg: MIUI))

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you flash a Coolpad device using SP Flashtool.  The device stick at Fmmi mode.

To get out of this, just open ADB Tool ([Minimal ADB and fastboot](https://devs-lab.com/download-minimal-adb-fastboot-tool.html)).

Then type the following:

```
adb devices 

adb shell fctest system reboot
```

Your phone should boot normally.

Comment: Did you see the title of the question, esQmo? Quoting it: "Adb Tool showing No Devices Found". So no `adb shell` there. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I think OP didn't check if the device is detected by adb devices... The phone should be detected in Fastmmi mode as an ADB device

Comment: My device is conected properly to my pc, but still I am getting No Device Found Massage, when i type adb shell fctest fectory reboot

Comment: Check for drivers